# RESTful API conventions for resource identifiers

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, uri

Suppose I have the following endpoints for users as:

```
GET users
POST users
GET users/:id e.g., users/1
PUT users/:id
DELETE users/:id
```

Now some of my implementations have endpoints where the id is mongo generated. So its not numeric, its a string.
But I have other endpoints which are like users/some_sub_resource.

Not exactly the case, I just want to know how can I differentiate between whether a sub-resource is being accessed or a specific user is being accessed if the resource id is not numeric, I don't want the resource id to be enforced as numeric, because there are existing projects which use alphanumeric strings as resource ids.

Comment: check out [these Google REST API design conventions](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names). Hope it helps.

Comment: What Framework do you use for your Resources? Jersey/Sping?

Comment: Express JS is the framework.